# Is that able to fully draw MenuItem?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, menuitem, ownerdrawn

I have create my control that can Redraw All MenuItem in Form by using MenuItem DrawItem() and MeasureItem().
After i run the program, the MenuItem is Redrawn, as i expected, but there something bother me, that the MenuItem is not fully Drawn ( Leave little white space ) like this

[image: My Application with custom MenuItem DrawItem()]
My Application with custom MenuItem DrawItem()

as in the picture, there some little white space that not drawn, is that able to draw full without leaving any whitespace like this

[image: AIMP3 Context Menu]
AIMP3 Context Menu

in C# ? if so, what methods must i use ?

this is some piece of my code

```
        public static void RenderMenu(Object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e, Boolean isUseKeyboardAccelerator, Image image)
        {
            Boolean selected = ( e.State & DrawItemState.Selected ) == DrawItemState.Selected;

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(StyleBrush.Menu, 0, 0, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);

            if ( selected )
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);

            if ( ( (MenuItem)sender ).Text == "-" )
            {
                Int32 vCenter = e.Bounds.Top + ( e.Bounds.Height / 2 ) - 1;

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ControlDark, e.Bounds.Left + 1, vCenter, ( e.Bounds.Left + e.Bounds.Width - 2 ), vCenter);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ControlLightLight, e.Bounds.Left + 1, vCenter + 1, ( e.Bounds.Left + e.Bounds.Width - 2 ), vCenter + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                RenderString(sender, e, selected, isUseKeyboardAccelerator);

                if ( ( (MenuItem)sender ).Checked )
                {
                    MenuGlyph menuGlyph;

                    if ( ( (MenuItem)sender ).RadioCheck )
                        menuGlyph = MenuGlyph.Bullet;
                    else
                        menuGlyph = MenuGlyph.Checkmark;

                    ControlPaint.DrawMenuGlyph(e.Graphics,
                        e.Bounds.Left + ( StyleVariable.MarginLeft + StyleVariable.GlyphBackgroundWidth + StyleVariable.MarginRight - SystemInformation.MenuCheckSize.Width ) / 2,
                        e.Bounds.Top + ( e.Bounds.Height - SystemInformation.MenuCheckSize.Height ) / 2 + 1,
                        SystemInformation.MenuCheckSize.Width, SystemInformation.MenuCheckSize.Height, menuGlyph,
                        selected ? SystemColors.HighlightText : SystemColors.MenuText,
                        selected ? SystemColors.Highlight : SystemColors.Menu);
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( image != null )
                    {
                        if ( ( (MenuItem)sender ).Enabled )
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, e.Bounds.Left + StyleVariable.MarginLeft, e.Bounds.Top + ( ( e.Bounds.Height - StyleVariable.GlyphBackgroundHeight ) / 2 ), StyleVariable.GlyphBackgroundWidth, StyleVariable.GlyphBackgroundHeight);
                        else
                            ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled(e.Graphics, image, e.Bounds.Left + StyleVariable.MarginLeft, e.Bounds.Top + ( ( e.Bounds.Height - StyleVariable.GlyphBackgroundHeight ) / 2 ), SystemColors.Menu);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you take into account any padding above or below the menu item, which is why it looks "short". If you are talking about the border, then you need to set the background color of the menu itself I believe, its difficult to decipher from your question exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: **MenuItem** does not have *padding* or *margin*, and that whitespace is inaccessible in code, and what DrawBackground() method do is same as FillRectangle, and still leaving a white space.

Comment: What you are seeing is the background of the **Menu** not the menu item, so you can't fix that problem in the menu item drawing code...

Comment: then is there any way to redraw **Menu** background ?

Comment: 1) No, this does not look like the menu background. 2) there is no white space around the menuitems, only around the whole block. If you have more than one you can see they are one contiguous block. - Do take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235627/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-a-menustrip)!! Loks like [ToolStripProfessionalRenderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.aspx) is the answer..

Comment: @TaW is that method can be used for MenuItem / not the ToolStrip family ?

Comment: Hm you may be right here. Maybe you want to test if it does what you want for ToolStripItems and, if it does, switch..?

Comment: yeah, for some reason / if full redrawing MainMenu / MenuItem is not really possible, i'll switch to ToolStripItem