# What is the name of the process to use seamless textures in form designing?

Tags: vb.net, forms, textures

In certain programs and applications, when I looked at their installation files they had some images only a few pixels say 40px in height and 1px in width. 
I learned from that time that image files are used seamlessly to create textures for certain parts of their programs "window" or "form".

I would like to know how to recreate this in visual basic. Let's take a simple example to use: I have a panel and inside this panel I want the seamless texture to repeat so that when the user re-sizes the form the image isn't cropped or not visibly stretched.

Also take the example of the image below showing the title bar in iTunes.

[image: 1]]

(I have already tried searching examples of this, but I don't know what the method is called and online results focus mainly on the words "seamless" and "design", showing things like Illustrator)

Comment: I am not sure what I am supposed to see in the image, but have you tried `.BackgroundImage` and `.BackgroundImageLayout` as Stretch?

Comment: @Plutonix the gradient texture

Comment: For a menu or toolbar, you can use a custom Renderer [C# example for menu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32356946/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix except i'm not editing the menu strip, i'm editing a panel.

Comment: Well, it *looks like* a toolbar.  Otherwise `GoTo Comment1:` use an image of the exact size and tile it:  http://i.imgur.com/48LF59T.png

Answer (score 0):

Background image in Tile or Stretch mode

Comment: It probably more flexible to handle that in the paint event.  You could use any 2 user defined colors for the gradient blend whereas you cannot include an image of every possible color combination