# How can we highlight active menu-item on clicking menu strip item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, menustrip

I am working on a desktop application in C# WinForms. I have used menustrip to navigate between different panels. The problem which I am facing is I cannot highlight the active color of the menustrip icon. A pictorial description will 
explain better what I want to achive.

This is my menu strip

[image]

and on  click **MenuStripItem** I want to achieve this

[image]

In short I want to the menu strip item to stay highlighted when I press ***Click*** on it just like ***Search and Edit*** in the picture and afterwards if I click on 
***New Customers*** then it must be highlighted as ***Search & Edit***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the border color of Winforms menu dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307778/change-the-border-color-of-winforms-menu-dropdown-list)

Comment: Would using a `ToolStrip` be a better option?  You could then add toggle buttons onto the `ToolStrip` and set the button corresponding to the active panel to be `Checked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ToolStrip` instead and set items `Checked` property to true. To do so, you can handle `ItemClicked` event of `ToolStrip` and check items this way:

```
private void toolStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ToolStripButton item in ((ToolStrip)sender).Items)
    {
        if (item != e.ClickedItem)
            item.Checked = false;
        else
            item.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

This way it shows a border around checked item. If for any reason you are not satisfied with appearance, you can simply customize the appearance of checked item by creating a custom renderer and assigning it as renderer of the `ToolStrip` this way:

```
public class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public MyRenderer() : base(new MyColorTable())
    {
    }
}

public class MyColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color ButtonCheckedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return ButtonPressedGradientBegin; }
    }
    public override Color ButtonCheckedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return ButtonPressedGradientEnd; }
    }
    public override Color ButtonCheckedGradientMiddle
    {
        get { return ButtonPressedGradientMiddle; }
    }
}
```

And assign the renderer in `Load` event of in constructor of your form after initialize components this way:

```
toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
```

This way, it shows the checked item as highlighted.

Comment: Thank you man it helped me a lot. It is better to use toolstrip instead of menustrip. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The selected item can be changed on `Paint` (not sure if there is  more appropriate event):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ToolStripItem activeToolStripItem = null;
    menuStrip1.Paint += (o, e) => activeToolStripItem?.Select();
    menuStrip1.ItemClicked += (o, e) => activeToolStripItem = e.ClickedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background colour of the clicked item on the MenuStrip as follows:

```
private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in ((ToolStrip)sender).Items)
    {
        if (item != e.ClickedItem)
            item.BackColor = Color.White;
        else
            item.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
    }
}
```