# c# menustrip custom colors - where can i set foreground?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I didn't find where can I set sub-menus foreground color globally (not one by one) in a `MenuStrip`. Red arrows on picture where I like to change foreground color.
I found [ToolstripCustomizer](http://toolstripcustomizer.codeplex.com/) tool, but it's can't set this color.

Edit: (Foreground color = Text color)

[image: current menustrip]

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13235627/1997232).

Comment: It's still not answers my question. I Would like set TEXT color globally,

Comment: There is no word "text" in your question. To set text color use menu `ForeColor` property.

Comment: "sub-menus foreground color" means textcolor in my question.
menustrip forecolor only sets upper line (see white chars)
all others can be changed one-by-one, and this is what i don't want to do.