# Change of the background color in minimized MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application with a MenuStrip. BackColor is blue, but when the window is resized (in the image you see only left corner of the menu) and I want to display other hidden items, the background is not blue.

How can I change the background color?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this : [ToolStripProfessionalRenderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.aspx)

```
public class MyToolStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    /* override styling/drawing here */
}

MenuStrip strip = new MenuStrip();

strip.Renderer = new MyToolStripRenderer();

//this will set RenderMode to "Custom"
```

[Exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235627/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-a-menustrip) :

```
public  class TestColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get { return Color.Red; }
    }

    public override Color MenuBorder  //added for changing the menu border
    {
        get { return Color.Green; }
    }
```

**You would use it like this:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    menuStrip1.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new TestColorTable());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me before WinForms hell.